# Create a dynamic method at runtime using format() in python

Tags: python

I am trying read a csv file having test case name (method name) along with parameters and trying to create a method name with parameters at runtime as below:

```
@pytest.mark.regression
def “{}({}):”.format(functionname, ‘, ‘.join(parameters))
```

It is showing an error message of identifier expected

I want to create function as above which can be used to execute with pytest marker command.

Comment: If this did work, how would it run? Your functions don't have bodies

Comment: please read about how to write functions https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Strings in Python must be quoted with plain quotes `"` and `'`, not with `“` or `‘`. Anyway, it is not clear what *problem you are trying to solve* this way. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and give appropriate context for the problem. It would help, at the very least, to understand specifically what "at runtime" means here. Is it good enough to have one program that reads the .csv file and writes out a .py file, and then separately run `pytest` to use the .py file that was written?

Comment: What's your end goal here? Some sort of Pytest parametrization?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the global function [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```py
import pytest

def createFunc(name, params, code):
    exec('''
@pytest.mark.regression
def {}({}):
    {}
''''.format(name, ', '.join(params), code), globals(), globals())
```

Usage:

```py
createFunc('test', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'print(a + b + c)')
test(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing correctly, you want to parametrize a Pytest test function to read test cases from a file (`input_csv.test_csvdata()` from that comment).

You can use the `pytest_generate_tests()` hook and `metafunc.parametrize` for that.

```
# Stand-in for `test_csvdata()`.
def get_test_csvdata():
    yield {'TCID': 'aaa', 'Template_name': 'temp', 'File_Type': 'aaa'}
    yield {'TCID': 'bbb', 'Template_name': 'temp', 'File_Type': 'bbb'}


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "csv_test_data" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        ids = []
        datas = []
        for datum in get_test_csvdata():
            ids.append(datum.pop("TCID"))
            datas.append(datum)
        metafunc.parametrize("csv_test_data", datas, ids=ids)


def test_csvdata(csv_test_data):
    print(csv_test_data)
    assert isinstance(csv_test_data, dict)
```

Running this via `py.test -sv` prints:

```
scratch_276.py::test_csvdata[aaa] {'Template_name': 'temp', 'File_Type': 'aaa'}
PASSED
scratch_276.py::test_csvdata[bbb] {'Template_name': 'temp', 'File_Type': 'bbb'}
PASSED
```

so you can see `TCID` for each test is in the name of the test, and the test gets the rest of the dict as an argument.